# redirecting output of command prompt to a text file using java in windows

Tags: java

I am launching command prompt using java by following code

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process proc = rt.exec("cmd /c start cmd.exe /K \"dir > D:\test1.txt");
```

after executing second line I am getting error as 'Access is denied' and I can't redirect output of command prompt to a text file.

Can somebody please help?

Comment: Read up about how to achieve this using ProcessBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

Double the backslash after `D:`, so that it's not inserting a tab (`\t`) in the command string:

```
Process proc = rt.exec("cmd /c start cmd.exe /K \"dir > D:\\test1.txt");
```

You will also need to fix that quote (`\"`) you inserted, because it's not ended. Either remove it, or add an appropriate end-quote (at the end?).

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Process proc = rt.exec("cmd /c start cmd.exe /K \"dir);

 OutputStream = proc.getOutputStream();
```

And then write the output to the file

Backslashes are used before escape characters in java. You need to format the path properly

Comment: Thanks Andreas and Ankit. By replacing by '\\' it worked fine.